# Why isn't this goroutine run, even with a `time.Sleep`?

Tags: go, goroutine, go-scheduler

Take this piece of code:

```golang
func main() {
    var x int
    go func() {
        for {
            x++
        }
    }()
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    fmt.Println("x =", x)
}
```

Why does `x` equal `0` at the end? I understand that Go's scheduler needs the `time.Sleep()` call to pickup the goroutine but why it isn't doing so?

***Hint:*** Putting a `time.Sleep()` or a call to `runtime.Gosched()` inside the for loop fixes this code. But why?

***Update:*** Check the following version of the same code:

```
func main() {
    var x int
    go func() {
        for i := 0; i < 10000; i++ {
            x++
        }
    }()
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    fmt.Println("x =", x)
}
```

Curiously the code inside the goroutine now is executed and `x` is no longer 0. Does the compiler do any optimization here?

Comment: Your code has a race condition (concurrent read & write of variable `x`), therefore the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @Adrian but I'm waiting before reading `x`. You can even increase the sleep time to be sure. And the point of my question is why `x` is `0`?

Comment: It doesn't matter - your goroutine runs an infinite loop, so no matter how long you wait to read it, there is still a concurrent write. The answer to your question is "you have a race condition, so the behavior is undefined".

Comment: @Adrian but it's not `undefined`. You'll get `0` every single time you run this code while I expect to get anything but 0.

Comment: @HamedMomeni I believe there is some confusion about what "undefined" means. It means *anything* is a valid output of this program. Undefined behavior doesn't mean "of a small set of expected results and we can guess which ones with some probability." This program is undefined such that it could do anything at all; print anything, not print anything, delete files, fail to terminate. *Anything* would be considered a correct output of the compiler. It's not a bad question in exploring how the Go compiler happens to be implemented, but undefined is *undefined*.

Comment: @RobNapier yes you are right and I apologize for my mistake. Here I'm just trying to understand how the compiler or the scheduler works in this specific situation.

Comment: There is no answer. This code is fundamentally broken in one of the few ways that is even possible in Go. Examining the results from any given run or set of runs of fundamentally broken code is fruitless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's important to know what you're asking here. There is no promise in Go that this program will do anything in particular, because the program is invalid. But as an exploration of the optimizer, it can be interesting to give some insight on how it is currently implemented. Any program that relied on this information would be very fragile and invalid, but still it's a curiosity.

We can compile the program, and then look at the output. I particularly like the two versions you've given, because they let use see the differences. I've done my decompilation using Hopper (these are compiled with go1.14 darwin/amd64).

In the second case, the goroutine looks like you'd think it would:

```
void _main.main.func1(int arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4, int arg5, int arg6) {
    rax = arg6;
    for (rcx = 0x0; rcx < 0x2710; rcx = rcx + 0x1) {
            *rax = *rax + 0x1;
    }
    return;
}
```

Nothing too surprising here. But what about the first case that you're curious about:

```
_main.main.func1:
    goto _main.main.func1;
```

It becomes a noop. Quite literally; here's the assembly:

```
                     _main.main.func1:
000000000109d1b0         nop                                                    ; CODE XREF=_main.main.func1+1
000000000109d1b1         jmp        _main.main.func1                            ; _main.main.func1
```

How does this happen? Well, the compiler can look at this code:

```
go func() {
    for {
        x++
    }
}()
```

And it knows that nothing ever reads `x`. There's no way anything ever could read `x`, because there is no locking around `x` and this goroutine never terminates. So there's nothing that can ever read `x` *after* this goroutine completes. See [The Go Memory Model](https://golang.org/ref/mem) for more about what it means for something to happen before something else or after something else.

"But I do read x!" No you don't. That would be invalid code and the compiler knows you didn't write invalid code. Who would do that when there's a race detector telling you this is invalid? So since the compiler can clearly see that nothing ever reads `x`, there is no reason to bother updating it.

In your limited-loop example, the goroutine terminates, so it could be possible that something reads `x` after that. The compiler isn't smart enough to notice that no *valid* read is ever made and so it doesn't optimize this as well as it could. Maybe a future compiler will be smart enough to output 0 in both cases. And maybe a future compiler will be smart enough to completely delete your no-op goroutine in the first case.

But the key point here is that the infinite-loop case is completely correct, though slightly less efficient than it could be. And the non-infinite-loop case is also completely correct, though quite a lot less efficient as it could be.

Comment: Well thanks. This is the answer I was looking for. I had my suspicion that it's a compiler optimization issue. Thanks for confirming it. And sorry for posting invalid code. I just had to know how it worked (or didn't in this case).

Comment: It's a completely valid question IMO, and educational. I think "why does undefined behavior do surprising things?" questions tend to touch a Stack Overflow nerve. :D

Answer (score 2):

This is a general multiprocessing problem, not specific to goroutines nor Go.

There is no guarantee on the order of execution of statements in your code. For example, the following sequence is possible (assuming "G" is your goroutine and "M" is code in `main`):

1. M: `x` defined
2. M: `G` defined and called
3. M: `Sleep` called
4. M: `Sleep` finished
5. M: `Println` (`x = 0`)
6. G: `x++`
7. G: `x++`
8. ...  (some number of times, maybe even 0)
9. Program ends

To observe some interleaving try:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    var x int

    go func() {
        for {
            time.Sleep(time.Second) 
            x++
        }
    }()
    time.Sleep(5*time.Second)
    fmt.Println("x =", x)
}
```

However, there are still no guarantees. To have any guarantees use any synchronization technique, e.g. channels.

Comment: I understand that this code has a race condition but I'm wondering why `x` is 0 every time without exception. For example change the sleep duration to a nanosecond inside the for loop in your version of the code. Now `x` is not 0 anymore.

Comment: @HamedMomeni Accidental interleaving can depend on many factors, the sleep might not be the most relevant thing here (see the other answer for a more comprehensive analysis).